# MySQL Query "How long ago" + 6hours

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

With the help of a friend, I got a webpage going that tracks different stats and saves it in an `SQL` database.

One of the information that returns, is when the latest score was submitted to the database. It works fine, but the webhost is in a different timezone and I am unable to change that timezone.

So therefore I was thinking about changing our query to one which returns how long ago the score was added.

Current code:

```
$statement = $adapter->query("
    select name, 
        SUM(score_1) as score_1, 
        SUM(score_2) as score_2, 
        SUM(score_3) as score_3,
        (SUM(score_1)+SUM(score_2)+SUM(score_3)) as total, 
        DATE_FORMAT(MAX(creation_time), '%d %b %H:%i') as creation_time 
    from score_entry 
    WHERE DATE(creation_time) = CURDATE() 
    group by name ORDER BY total DESC");
```

It grabs the information stored in the past day (from 00:00 this day), and I'm not sure if that is also affected by the incorrect timezone.

After a lot of searching around, I can't seem to find the solution to my exact problem.

I have tried to set the timezone in MySQL, but it's a shared host by `Namecheap`, they don't allow it.

Comment: As [David Frank](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1107109/david-frank) pointed out, you can change the timezone in `MySQL`, just keep in mind, that changing it in the **query**, will not be reflected in `php`, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [time zone documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html).

Using the `SET time_zone = timezone;` command you will be able to set the time zone on a per-connection basis.

In addition, storing dates in a `TIMESTAMP` column makes MySQL convert the time to UTC and then it converts it back to the current time zone when you access it. Thus it makes storing and retrieving time zone agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the time zone in your PHP script using the posted solution. It's also possible to send it the datetime to use in your query using PHP's date function.